# Не отображается одно из сообщений об отправке формы (JS)

Tags: javascript, html-form

Здравствуйте!

Есть форма обратной связи на сайте. Если необходимые поля не заполнены, то она пишет об ошибке ( работает ), однако сообщение об отправке так и не появляется ( если нужные поля заполнены ).

В чем может быть ошибка? Сайт на UMI. Спасибо!

Код:

```html
<xsl:template match="udata[@form_id]" mode="content-content-contacts-form">
        <div class="form_block">
            <p class="top_text">Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!</p>
            <form action="/webforms/dispatch/" method="POST">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()//field[@name = 'contacts_name']" mode="content-content-contacts-form-field">
                    <xsl:with-param name="id">name</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()//field[@name = 'contacts_email']" mode="content-content-contacts-form-field">
                    <xsl:with-param name="id">email</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()//field[@name = 'contacts_phone']" mode="content-content-contacts-form-field" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()//field[@name = 'contacts_message']" mode="content-content-contacts-form-field-message" />

                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" mode="webforms-system-fields" />

                <a class="send_data" href="javascript:void(0)">Отправить</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

JS:

```js
// Check empty inputs
  $('.send_data').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    if ( !$('#name').val() && !$('#email').val() ) {
      $('#name, #email').addClass('empty');
      $('.top_text').fadeIn().addClass('red').text('Пожалуйста, заполните все необходимые поля');
    } else if ( !$('#name').val() ) {
      $('#name').addClass('empty');
      $('.top_text').fadeIn().addClass('red').text('Пожалуйста, заполните все необходимые поля');
    } else if ( !$('#email').val() ) {
      $('#email').addClass('empty');
      $('.top_text').fadeIn().addClass('red').text('Пожалуйста, заполните все необходимые поля');
    } else {
        var $form = $(this).parents('form');

        $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $('.top_text').fadeIn().removeClass('red').text('Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!');
            }
        });
    }
   // $('.req').each(function() {
   //  if ( !$(this).val() ) {
   //   $(this).addClass('empty');
   //      $('.top_text').fadeIn().addClass('red').text('Пожалуйста, заполните все необходимые поля');
   //  }
   //    else {
   //      $('.top_text').fadeIn().removeClass('red').text('Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!');
   //    }
   // });
  });

  $('.req').focusin(function(event) {
   $(this).removeClass('empty');
  });
//////

});
```

Comment: Добавьте обработчик error в ajax и выведите в консоль ошибку, тогда станет понятно почему не работает

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Вот [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/xjpcL39c/2/)

Comment: https://db.tt/6ZOEzi1x

Comment: a [так](https://jsfiddle.net/xjpcL39c/3/) попробуйте

Comment: вроде бы всё работает, спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, обращайтесь